# The fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its non-negative half-axes removed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

> Determine whether the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its non-negative half-axes removed is trivial, infinite cyclic, or isomorphic to the figure eight space.
>   I found this answer:

[image]

Why do we have that $\alpha*\beta=\gamma$? I can't see how we have this homotopy or deformation.

PS: I think we are actually supposed to solve this by showing that we can find that the figure eight space is a deformation retract of this space, or homotopy equivalent. Do you see a way of doing this? I cannot really see how to define the deformations.

Comment: The path $\alpha*\beta$ passes through $x_0$ three times: in its endpoints, and in "the middle" (depending on the parametrization, but you see what I mean). In a path homotopy, we only need to leave the endpoints of the path fixed, so we are allowed to move the "middle point $x_0$" to the other side of the axes, and we get $\gamma$.

Comment: intuitively, you can push the point where $\alpha$ end and $\beta$ start away from $x_0$, while fixing the initial and end points of the loop $\alpha *\beta$ , and then you can push the loop onto $\gamma$

Comment: Thanks guys, I see what you mean!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one approach to the question in the postscript:

If we denote by $X$ the subspace of $\Bbb R^3 - \{ 0 \}$ whose fundamental group we are computing, one can show that the mapping $\Bbb R^3 - \{ 0 \} \to \Bbb S^2 \subset \Bbb R^3$ defined by $x \mapsto \frac{x}{||x||}$ restricts to a homotopy between $X$ and a sphere with three points deleted, namely $Y := \Bbb S^2 - \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$, and this restriction and the inclusion $Y \hookrightarrow X$ together comprise a homotopy equivalence $X \simeq Y$. The thrice-punctured sphere $Y$ is then homeomorphic (via, e.g., stereographic projection from one of the deleted points) to the plane with two points deleted, $\Bbb R^2 - \{p, q\}$, and this space is in turn homotopic to the figure eight space (see page 3 of [these notes of Munkres](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/Munkres-58.pdf) for some diagrams that indicate how to write down explicitly this latter homotopy equivalence).

Comment: Thank you very much! Just two questions: 1. You say that you have a homotopy equivalence, but is it also true that you have a deformation retraction? 2.Is it a small typo at the beginning when you write $\mathbb{R}^4-\{0\}$? Anyway, thank yuu very much, this was very smart!

Comment: I emant $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$, you meant $\mathbb{R}^3$ - the relevant axes?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. (1) Yes, this is also a deformation retraction onto an appropriate embedding of the figure eight space in $X$. (2) Yes, the first sentence had a typo; it was supposed to read (and now does), "If we denote by $X$ the subspace *of*...".

Comment: Minor error : Since the non-negative axes are removed from $\Bbb R^3$, won't it mean that the points $(1,0,0)$ , $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ are removed from $\Bbb S^2$?

Comment: @Error404 You're right, and thanks for pointing this out. This was a few years ago, but I imagine I was mislead by the illustration. In any case, I've patched up the answer, which is unchanged in spirit.